# Lenovo webcam/camera option?

Tags: laptop, webcam, camera

I am selecting options for a Lenovo laptop, and under the CAMERA section, it gives two options:

"0.3MP webcam with MIC"
Or
"720p HD Camera with MIC"

What is the difference b/w the two? What's the difference b/w a camera and a webcam? Which one should I go for?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the 0.3mp Webcam with MIC is the built in camera on the laptop, it will be lower quality than the external one.

Go for the 720p HD Camera with MIC as it will be much higher quality.